# How to push a box with physics engine by another object?

Tags: physics, collision

I want to push a box by an animated character in Blender 2.8.
First I tried to animate the box by `keyframes` but this looks very unnatural.

[image]

[image]

I think this will look much more realistic when the animated character pushes the box with help of physic engine and collusion logic.

I played around with some settings regarding this in `Collusion` and `Rigid Body`. But it is pretty hard to understand what is going on there as a beginner.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better if you use a copy location constraint on the box by a hand bone. You can set keyframes for the influence, so the character can release it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could try setting the box to an active rigid body type and then the character will be passive. when you animate the character with keyframes it will interact with the box.